# Rs422 lines passives

Tags: rs422

I am using an rs422 driver and receiver IC for connecting 2 different boards.
Now I have seen many circuits of rs422 which have passives connected in them. Why is that ? And how are they calculated ? The precise values of resistors and capacitors.

What is the need for such passives please ?

Comment: Both your RS422 questions, which if they were of sufficient quality could have been combined to spare clutter, are very easily researched with Google, by typing... "RS422" for a start. Yet you show no effort taken in either of them.

Comment: Thank u for ur wise comments. If someone asks all doubts in 1 post down vote saying put them in diff posts. If put in diff posts merge it.

Comment: @Asmyldof Splitting different questions into different posts is the correct way to do it. Especially in this case, since bus termination and ESD concerns are not really related topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistor on receiver side is a termination resistor. Think the output driver as a current source driving a negative or positive current over the termination. The receiver senses the polarity of the voltage caused by the current. You can add caps as well for an AC termination.

Here's a [TI document (SLLA070D)](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla070d/slla070d.pdf?keyMatch=rs422&tisearch=Search-EN-TechDocs) that describes the different terminations.